# Why the Json module cannot serialize date object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a error coming as below

```
{
        "statusCode": 500,
        "body": "\"An error occurred: Object of type date is not JSON serializable\""
    },
```

and below is the code implementation  to handle the error.

```
def format_item(item):
    if item is None:
        return 0.0 if isinstance(item, (Decimal, float)) else ""
    elif isinstance(item, (Decimal, float)):
        return float(item)
    elif isinstance(item, (datetime, date)):
        if isinstance(item, date):
            return item.isoformat()  # Handle yyyy-mm-dd format
        elif isinstance(item, datetime):
            if item.hour == 0 and item.minute == 0 and item.second == 0:
                return item.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # Handle yyyy-mm-dd format
            else:
                return item.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # Handle yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format
    else:
        return "" if item is None else item


def stored_procedure_call(sp_name, id, entity):
    logging.info(f"Fetching DB connection details.")
    try:
        # Load env file
        load_dotenv()
        # Create the connection object
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=os.getenv('USER_NAME'),
            password=get_db_password(os.getenv('RDS_HOST')),
            host=os.getenv('RDS_HOST'),
            database=os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
            port=os.getenv('PORT'))

        # Create a cursor
        cursor = conn.cursor()
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error("An unexpected error occurred: {}".format(error))

    try:

        # Call the stored procedure with the provided ID
        cursor.callproc(stored_procedure_name, [id, entity])
        conn.commit()

        result_list = []
        for result in cursor.stored_results():
            rows = result.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                result_list.append(list(row))
                logging.info(row)
        print("[RESULT LIST] :", result_list)

        if not result_list:
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps([])
            }

        else:
            result_list_serializable = [list(format_item(item) for item in tup) for tup in result_list]
            print('[RESULT SERIALIZER] :', result_list_serializable)

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'body': json.dumps(result_list)
        }

    except Exception as error:
        logging.error("An unexpected error occurred: {}".format(error))
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,  # Internal Server Error
            'body': json.dumps('An error occurred: {}'.format(str(error)))
        }

    finally:
        close_connection(cursor, conn)
```

What could be the possible issue.

The error seems to be quite common, and I have tried to implement the solution from other blogs or article. But it doesn't seem to be working. Please suggest

sample data:

```
[['4565b', 'Agi Ltd', 'Insight Dire', '2100', datetime.date(2023, 9, 21), datetime.date(2023, 10, 21), 'ABC', 'Dell E5 ', '4565b64f53e', datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 16, 17, 14)]]
```

Comment: I have added a sample data. Please have a look

Comment: As Joe has noted below in a comment, you made a mistake by serializing the wrong list. Voting to close as typo

Comment: Also, extracting a [mcve] could have answered parts of the question already.

Comment: As an aside, your handling of `None` doesn't make much sense in `format_item`. Inside a `if item is None:` you do another conditional checking if: `if isinstance(item, (Decimal, float))` but **`item` is `None`** so it will never be an instance of `Decimal` or `float`, it will always be an instance of the NoneType.  In your `else`, you then check `return "" if item is None else item` but `item` **can't be `None`** since that was the `if` condition!

Comment: I will keep that in mind, and cross check it. thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [json documentation](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), in json the type of a value can only be: (`str`), integer (`int`), float (`float`), object (`dict`), array (`list`/`tuple`), `true`, `false` or `null`.

If you want to put dates in a json object, you'll need to convert it to one of these types.
This can be done in several ways:

```py
item.timestamp() # Convert a datetime to an UNIX timestamp (works for datetime objects but not for date objects)
item.isoformat() # Convert a datetime to an ISO 8601 timestamp
item.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # Handle yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format
```

Note that you can also convert all non-serializable objects to `str` (like `str(item)`) by setting `default=str`.

```py
json.dumps(result_list, default=str)
```

Comment: well, as pointed out, the issue was wrong call of a variable in json.dum(). Now, data coming properly

Answer (score 2):

because datatime is not a native datatype in json. serializing into a string is easy, for json module to support datetime, it would also have to deserialize values in a json string into datetime which is not possible.

if you only want to serialize datatimes into strings, then this should work:
json.dumps(my_dictionary, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)

Comment: Have you noticed that they call `format_item` and convert datetime into string there?

Comment: @trincot, but doesn't OP call that to make result_list_serializable, but then dump result_list?

Comment: Yes, @Joe, and *that* is the problem. The OP surely knows that datetime is not a native datatype in JSON, but they made a mistake.

Comment: the sample data is a list of list